# which utility produces "Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.6.1 (none) /dev/console"

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I am playing with Yocto Thud 2.6.1.

I want to know which utility / program / library is responsible for producing following line:

'Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.6.1 (none) /dev/console'

[image: Yocto Login Prompt]
Thanks

Comment: It is defined in `meta-poky/conf/distro/poky.conf` file with [DISTRO_NAME](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-DISTRO_NAME) variable.

Comment: Hey Nayfe,
Thank you for the answer. From poky.conf we do get to know the current version of Yocto.
However, after grepping for some more time I found that 
/etc/issue & /etc/issue.net is responsible for producing that line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines before the login are from the /etc/issue and /etc/issue.net files.
You can modify them by creating a bbappend file with your own issue and issue.net files.

Note that Yocto will still append the `Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro) 2.6.1` lines.

Taking a look at the `base_file_3.0.14.bb` (my current version):

```
BASEFILESISSUEINSTALL ?= "do_install_basefilesissue"

[...]

do_install_basefilesissue () {
    if [ "${hostname}" ]; then
        echo ${hostname} > ${D}${sysconfdir}/hostname
    fi

    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/issue*  ${D}${sysconfdir}
        if [ -n "${DISTRO_NAME}" ]; then
        printf "${DISTRO_NAME} " >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue
        printf "${DISTRO_NAME} " >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue.net
        if [ -n "${DISTRO_VERSION}" ]; then
            distro_version_nodate=${@'${DISTRO_VERSION}'.replace('snapshot-${DATE}','snapshot').replace('${DATE}','')}
            printf "%s " $distro_version_nodate >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue
            printf "%s " $distro_version_nodate >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue.net
        fi
        printf "\\\n \\\l\n" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue
        echo >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue
        echo "%h"    >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue.net
        echo >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/issue.net
    fi
}
```

Yo need to disable this `do_install_basefileissue` and set your own install instead:

base-file_%.bbappend:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI_prepend = " file://issue \
                    file://issue.net "
BASEFILESISSUEINSTALL = "do_install_basefilesissuecustom"

do_install_basefilesissuecustom () {
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/issue*  ${D}${sysconfdir}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Pierre! 
Can you tell me who calls /etc/issue or /etc/issue.net ?
Ideally, after kernel is loaded just before rfs starts some code must be invoking it right ?

Comment: I think it is "called" by getty, or a tty-type program who handle serial communication. The SSH daemon also use it (if it is configured).

Comment: The recipe, and directory are now base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb.